# Will the world bosses be available on release?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria there are two new world raid bosses (that we know of):

- [Salyis's Warband](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/mists-of-pandaria/world-boss/salyis-warband)
- [The Sha of Anger](http://mop.wowhead.com/npc=60491)

We also know that Blizzard is only opening up raids some time after the initial release of Mists of Pandaria ([Source](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5058396227?page=1#1)).

Will the world raid bosses be available on release, or will they be delayed like the normal raids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be available upon launch.

> There will be two outdoor world bosses, along with the Mogu’shan Vaults raid instance, available when Mists of Pandaria first launches.

Thats from a [link](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/5395467/World_of_Warcraft_Mists_of_Pandaria_Raid_Preview-31_07_2012) in your source.

Edit: I'm aware that there is an ambiguity but as I understand it the world bosses are ready at launch.

**Update: it has been 100% confirmed that "the two world bosses will be available at release day" in an [MMO-Champion translation of an EU interview](http://www.mmo-champion.com/content/2902-Gamescom-Interviews-Mobile-Armory-Free-LFR-Changes-Blue-Posts-TCG-Art) (original source at previous link).**

Comment: Except they've since announced "Mogu’shan Vaults opens up one week after Mists of Pandaria launches" (from the OP), so their plans have obviously changed at least with normal raids. Hence my curiousity...

Comment: Although they do mention MV potentially delayed in the link, but no mention of the world bosses.  I'll see if anyone has anything concrete, but it's probably a good sign that they'll be there on release.

Comment: I remember reading something that World Bosses will be able at launch but I can't remember where or if it was just my imagination. But I'll keep browsing and maybe I find something more definite. Good question anyway! Would be fun stumbling on a world boss first days in :)

Comment: Updated your answer with a link to official confirmation.